# C - Price look-up program

Tags: c, loops

I was asked to make a C program that act as a 'price lookup' where a user enter a product name and the program will print it's name and price which is stored in a file. If the item is not present in the file, the program will let the user know. The program will keep looping as long as the user wants to search. I did the coding using Dev C++, however after i run the code, the program got stuck after a few loops, and it's random. Could you guys detect any problem with my coding, or is it just the problem with Dev C++? I include my code below. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *items;
    char *mode="r";
    char pName[50];
    float pPrice;
    char p1Name[50];
    int value=0;
    char respond='Y';
    char s[50];

    items=fopen("Product_Name_Price.txt", mode);

    if(items==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file Product_Name_Price.txt!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("File has been successfully opened\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the product you wish to look for\n");
        scanf("%s", &p1Name);

        while(strcmp(p1Name, pName) !=0)
        {
            fscanf(items,"%s %f", pName, &pPrice);

            //printf("%s\t%.2f\n", pName, pPrice);

            //value=strcmp(p1Name, pName);

            if(strcmp(p1Name, pName) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\t%.2f\n", pName, pPrice);
            }   
        }

        /*
        else
        {
            printf("No data in system\n");
        }  
        */

        printf("Do you wish to look up for more item? (Y/N)\n");
        scanf("%s", &respond);

    }while(respond=='Y'|| respond=='y');

    printf("This program is closing\n");

    fclose(items);
}
```

Comment: scanf %s is for strings, %c for a character. Undefined behaviour caused by that cause random things.

Comment: Is this a C program, or a C++ program? Pick _one_. (If it's a C++ program, why are you writing in C idioms and using C features?)

Comment: I'm doing it in c program.

Comment: Then why is the question tagged [tag:c++]? Why are you writing it in a C++ IDE? Makes no sense.

Comment: I was asked to do the program in C, and I am using the stuffs I learned from my lecturer and a bit here and there that she doesn't taught me. Maybe I looked into the wrong source and picked up some C++ stuffs.

Comment: Possible [buffer overflow with `scanf`](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanf+buffer+overflow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: If you are really using C++, you need to reduce your issues by using `std::string`, `std::cin` and `std::getline`.

Comment: See also `toupper()` and `tolower()` so you don't have to perform a lower case compare and an upper case compare.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am using C program. I am still trying to understand how to incorporate tolower() function into my program.

Comment: Try this: `while (toupper(respond) == 'Y');`  or `while (tolower(respond) == 'y');`

Comment: You `#include <conio.h>` and if that hints of using a Windows compiler you will also have `strupr`, `strlwr` and `stricmp`available to you, when checking the product name. When this is working you might like to also use `strstr` which will help you find a *partial* product name.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks. Do you happen to know why my scanf for y/n question is ignored after I changed `scanf("%s", &respond)` to `scanf("%c", &respond)` ?

Comment: Add a space before `%c`, as in `scanf(" %c", &respond)`, otherwise you'll just read the previous `newline` in the input buffer. This makes it ignore all whitespace before a "proper" character. OTOH the `%s` format you were using, does ignore such leading whitespace anyway. `scanf` is tricky.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behaviour because your `scanf("%s", &response)` reads into `response` as if it were an array of sufficient size for the string being read — that size is *at least* 2 (including null terminator), but `response` is just *one* character. You blew up your stack and corrupted memory and then all bets are off.

You could write `scanf("%c", &response)` instead to actually read a single character, though you'd be better off switching to modern, safer tools if you're writing a C++ program.

Comment: I did change from %s to %c and it ignores the scanf for y/n question. Do you know why?

Comment: @SafiuddinMansor: It doesn't "ignore" anything. You probably need to eat up the trailing newline. Please perform some research before asking questions.